# Should I count up in Perl 6 with a sequence or a range?

Tags: range, raku, seq

Perl 6 has [lazy lists](https://docs.perl6.org/language/list.html#Lazy_Lists), but it also has unbounded [Range](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Range) objects. Which one should you choose for counting up by whole numbers?

And there's unbounded [Range](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Range) with two dots:

```
0 .. *
```

There's the [Seq (sequence)](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Seq) with three dots:

```
0 ... *
```

A `Range` generates lists of consecutives thingys using their natural order. It inherits from [Iterable](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Iterable), but also [Positional](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Positional) so you can index a range. You can check if something is within a `Range`, but that's not part of the task.

A `Seq` can generate just about anything you like as long as it knows how to get to the next element. It inherits from [Iterable](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Iterable), but also [PositionalBindFailover](https://docs.perl6.org/type/PositionalBindFailover) which fakes the `Positional` stuff through a cache and list conversion. I don't think that a big deal if you're only moving from one element to the next.

I'm going back and forth on this. At the moment I'm thinking it's [Range](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Range).

Comment: the `perl6-language` mailing list or the `#perl6` IRC channel on freenode might be a better place for such a question...

Comment: No one will find the answer after a week. People find answers on Stackoverflow.

Comment: but stackoverflow is supposed to be more about practical problems and less about the intricacies of language semantics; I doubt you'd be satisfied with the pratical answer (use `Range` as `..` is shorter than `...` :p); mind, I'm happy to answer such questions, but I'm not sure it really fits here...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Semantically speaking, a `Range` is a static thing (a bounded set of values), a `Seq` is a dynamic thing (a value generator) and a lazy `List` a static view of a dynamic thing (an immutable cache for generated values).

*Rule of thumb:* Prefer static over dynamic, but simple over complex.

In addition, a `Seq` is an iterable thing, a `List` is an iterable positional thing, and a `Range` is an ordered iterable positional thing.

*Rule of thumb:* Go with the most generic or most specific depending on context.

As we're dealing with iteration only and are not interested in positional access or bounds, using a `Seq` (which is essentially a boxed `Iterator`) seems like a natural choice. However, ordered sets of consecutive integers are *exactly* what an integer `Range` represents, and personally that's what I would see as most appropriate for your particular use case.

When there is no clear choice, I tend to prefer ranges for their simplicity anyway (and try to avoid lazy lists, the heavy-weight).

Note that the language syntax also nudges you in the direction of `Range`, which are rather heavily Huffman-coded (two-char infix `..`, one-char prefix `^`).

Comment: @briandfoy: I added some rationale for my preferences

Comment: "*iteration always happens in terms of Seq anyway*" - I don't think `for 1..* { }` ever constructs a `Seq`. As I understand it, the `for` loop 1) sees that it got an `Iterable`, 2) calls `.iterator` on it to get an `Iterator`, 3) keeps calling [`.pull-one`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Iterator#method_pull-one) on that iterator until it gets an `IterationEnd`.

Answer (score 12):

Both `0 .. *` and `0 ... *` are fine.

- Iterating over them, for example with a `for` loop, has exactly the same effect in both cases. (Neither will leak memory by keeping around already iterated elements.)
- Assigning them to a `@` variable produces the same lazy Array.

So as long as you only want to count up numbers to infinity by a step of 1, I don't see a downside to either.

The `...` sequence construction operator is more generic though, in that it can also be used to

- count with a different step (`1, 3 ... *`)
- count downwards (`10 ... -Inf`)
- follow a geometric sequence (`2, 4, 8 ... *`)
- follow a custom iteration formula (`1, 1, *+* ... *`)

so when I need to do something like that, then I'd consider using `...` for any nearby and related "count up by one" as well, for consistency.

On the other hand:

- A `Range` can be indexed efficiently without having to generate and cache all preceding elements, so if you want to index your counter in addition to iterating over it, it is preferable. The same goes for other list operations that deal with element positions, like `reverse`: `Range` has efficient overloads for them, whereas using them on a `Seq` has to iterate and cache its elements first.
- If you want to count upwards to a variable end-point (as in `1 .. $n`), it's safer to use a `Range` because you can be sure it'll never count downwards, no matter what `$n` is. (If the endpoint is less than the startpoint, as in `1 .. 0`, it will behave as an empty sequence when iterated, which tends to get edge-cases right in practice.)
  Conversely, if you want to safely count downwards ensuring it will never unexpectedly count upwards, you can use `reverse 1 .. $n`.
- Lastly, a `Range` is a more specific/high-level representation of the concept of "numbers from x to y", whereas a `Seq` represents the more generic concept of "a sequence of values". A `Seq` is, in general, driven by arbitrary generator code (see [`gather`/`take`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/control#gather/take)) - the `...` operator is just semantic sugar for creating some common types of sequences. So it may feel more declarative to use a Range when "numbers from x to y" is the concept you want to express. But I suppose that's a purely psychological concern... :P

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between ".." (Range) and "..." (Seq):

```
$ perl6
> 1..10
1..10
> 1...10
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
> 2,4...10
(2 4 6 8 10)
> (3,6...*)[^5]
(3 6 9 12 15)
```

The "..." operator can intuit patterns!

https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#index-entry-..._operators

As I understand, you can traverse a Seq only once.  It's meant for streaming where you don't need to go back (e.g., a file).  I would think a Range should be a fine choice.